# exception didn't influence value

Tags: c++, exception

Here's the MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x=1;
    try {
        throw 3.14;
    }
    catch(double x) {
        x *= 2;
        cout << x<<endl;
    }
    cout << ++x;
    return 0;
}
```

What I expect `x` will be 7.28, but it shows 2. So the exception didn't change the value. Can anyone explain the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weird throwing doubles as exceptions.

Anyway - You have an outer `x` and and inner `x`. The inner being the one caught. This will catch the value 3.14, double it to 6.28 and print that. The outer one will remain unchanged.

So the final `cout` will increment the outer `x` (that has the value 1) and print that (2)

Comment: Why `x` has dual identity.  Does it mean `try&catch` can be seen an objects or function?

Comment: You have two doubles named `x`.